# Adding a validation error with a before_save callback or custom validator?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I have a model `Listing` that `belongs_to :user`. Alternatively, `User` `has_many :listings`. Each listing has a category field that classifies it (*dogs*, *cats*, etc). The `User` also has a boolean field called `is_premium`.

Here is how I am validating the category...

```
validates_format_of :category,
                    :with => /(dogs|cats|birds|tigers|lions|rhinos)/,
                    :message => 'is incorrect'
```

Let's say I only want to allow premium users to be able to add *tigers*, *lions*, and *rhinos*. How would I go about this? Would it be best to do it in a `before_save` method?

```
before_save :premium_check

def premium_check
  # Some type of logic here to see if category is tiger, lion, or rhino.
  # If it is, then check if the user is premium. If it's not, it doesn't matter.
  # If user isn't premium then add an error message.
end
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No, it won't work. I guess you should rather use custom validator instead.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
class Listing < ActiveRecord::Base    
  validate :premium_category

  private

  def premium_category
    if !user.is_premium && %w(tigers lions rhinos).include?(category))
      errors.add(:category, "not valid for non premium users")
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: "AND"? You mean "`&&`"?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to add validation errors doing the before_save you could raise an exception then add the error in the controller like this:

```
class Listing < ActiveRecord::Base    
  before_save :premium_category

  private

  def premium_category
    if !user.is_premium && %w(tigers lions rhinos).include?(category))
      raise Exceptions::NotPremiumUser, "not valid for non premium users"
    end
  end
end
```

Then in your controller do something like:

```
begin 
    @listing.update(listing_params)
    respond_with(@listing)
rescue Exceptions::NotPremiumUser => e
      @listing.errors.add(:base, e.message)
      respond_with(@listing)    
end
```

Then in your /lib folder add a class like this:

```
module Exceptions
  class NotPremiumUser < StandardError; end
end
```

But in your case I think using the validate method is a better solution.

Cheers,

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`validates_exclusion_of`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/HelperMethods.html#method-i-validates_exclusion_of):

```
validates :category, :exclusion => {
  :in => ['list', 'of', 'invalid'],
  :message => 'must not be premium category',
  :unless => :user_is_premium?
}

protected

def user_is_premium?
  self.user.premium?
end
```