# Lock value of database column based on boolean value in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I want to let a user edit the field `report.plan` only if `report.published = false`.  If `report.published = true` and they try to save a change, I want to throw an error.

I've written the following code to do this:

```
class Report < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :cannot_update_plan_after_published, on: :publish_plan!

  def publish_plan!(plan)
    self.plan = plan
    self.published = true
    self.save
  end

  private

    def cannot_update_plan_after_published
      if self.published?
        errors.add(:plan, "You cannot change the plan once it has been published.")
      end
    end
end
```

However, this is not working.  When I call `publish_plan!` on an already published report, it makes the save.  For example:

```
> f = Report.last
=> #<Report id: 12, plan: "a", published: false>
> f.publish_plan!("b")
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.4ms)  UPDATE "reports" SET "plan" = 'b', "updated_at" = '2014-09-18 18:43:47.459983' WHERE "reports"."id" = 12
   (9.2ms)  commit transaction
=> true
> f = Report.last
  Report Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "reports".* FROM "reports" ORDER BY "reports"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
=> #<Report id: 12, plan: "b", published: true>
> f.publish_plan!("c")
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.4ms)  UPDATE "reports" SET "plan" = 'c', "updated_at" = '2014-09-18 18:43:53.996191' WHERE "reports"."id" = 12
   (8.7ms)  commit transaction
=> true
> Report.last
  Report Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "reports".* FROM "reports" ORDER BY "reports"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
=> #<Report id: 12, plan: "c", published: true>
```

How do I get this field to become uneditable once `report.published = true`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the `on: :public_plan!`. That way, the validation should be run every time the model is saved.

```
validate :cannot_update_plan_after_published
```

See here for more details: [Adding a validation error with a before_save callback or custom validator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19544646/adding-a-validation-error-with-a-before-save-callback-or-custom-validator)

Also, for the validation method itself, change it to the following:

```
def cannot_update_plan_after_published
  if self.published? && self.published_changed? == false
    errors.add(:plan, "You cannot change the plan once it has been published.")
  end
end
```

This allows you to set it the first time publishing the plan.